# How would I make a recursive trace print out like this?

Tags: java, recursion

So I am trying to print out a trace of a recursive function of the Fibonacci sequence.

My output should be like this:

[image]

However, I am unsure of how to format this. I don't really know where to start.
I've tried this:

```
private static int fibCount;

public static long fibonacci(int n) {
    fibCount++;
    long result;
    if (n == 0 || n == 1) {
        result = n;
        System.out.printf("fib(%s)-->%s%n", n, result);
    } else {
        result = fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2);
        System.out.printf("fib(%s)%n", n);
    }
    return result;
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    fibonacci(5);
}
```

Which prints out

```
fib(1)-->1
fib(0)-->0
fib(2)
fib(1)-->1
fib(3)
fib(1)-->1
fib(0)-->0
fib(2)
fib(4)
fib(1)-->1
fib(0)-->0
fib(2)
fib(1)-->1
fib(3)
fib(5)
```

I feel like I need to use that fibCount variable (I made it just because I thought the indentations would rely on it), but I don't know if I should, or how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

- Split up your recursive calls (so you can print current call in between)
- pass in a `depth` parameter to keep track of how much to indent

```
public static long fibonacci(int depth, int n) {
    String indent = new String(new char[depth]).replace('\0', ' ');
    long result;
    if (n == 0 || n == 1) {
        result = n;
        System.out.printf(indent + "fib(%s)-->%s%n", n, result);
    } else {
        long first = fibonacci(depth+1, n - 1);
        System.out.printf(indent + "fib(%s)%n", n);
        long second = fibonacci(depth+1, n - 2);
        result = first + second;
    }
    return result;
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    fibonacci(0, 5);
}
```

**Output:**

```
    fib(1)-->1
   fib(2)
    fib(0)-->0
  fib(3)
   fib(1)-->1
 fib(4)
   fib(1)-->1
  fib(2)
   fib(0)-->0
fib(5)
   fib(1)-->1
  fib(2)
   fib(0)-->0
 fib(3)
  fib(1)-->1
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass in the level of indentation with each call.  Each time you recourse you can increased the indentation.

```
public static long fibonacci(int n) {
    return fibonacci(n, 1);
}

public static long fibonacci(int n, int indent) {
    System.out.printf("%"+indent+"s", "");
    long result;
    if (n == 0 || n == 1) {
        result = n;
        System.out.printf("fib(%s)-->%s%n", n, result);
    } else {
        result = fibonacci(n - 1, indent + 2) + fibonacci(n - 2, indent + 2);
        System.out.printf("fib(%s)%n", n);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: You can't pass `0` as width in a format string. Also, OP was after "infix" printout of current call.

Answer (score 0):

You should keep a sort of  indentation counter that gets incremented every time you enter your fibonacci function and decremented every time you leave it.

Then, when printing, put as many spaces as the current value of this counter just before the actual printing. For better viewing you can put twice as much spaces, but this is just a personal choice.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that in the real world, you'd only put in a trace like this (and particularly one using a static variable) as a temporary debugging measure, and delete the code before you put it into production.  If you want to leave it in production code, I'd look for a different solution.

First, if you're going to use a static variable for this, you need to make sure each recursive invocation restores its value afterwards.  It might be best to do this in a `finally` block, to make sure that the restoration always happens even if there's a `return` hidden somewhere inside the code (or in case of an exception):

```
public static long fibonacci(int n) {
    int saveFibCount = fibCount;
    fibCount++;
    try {
        fibCount++;
        long result;
        if (n == 0 || n == 1) {
            result = n;
            System.out.printf("fib(%s)-->%s%n", n, result);
        } else {
            result = fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2);
            System.out.printf("fib(%s)%n", n);
        }
        return result;
    } finally {
        fibCount = saveFibCount;
    }
}
```

Second, to get this into your indentation: Unfortunately, Java doesn't have a built-in method to return a string of `n` spaces.  You can write one easily enough (or use methods available in Apache Commons, I think), and use them this way:

```
        if (n == 0 || n == 1) {
            result = n;
            System.out.printf("%sfib(%s)-->%s%n", blanks(4*fibCount), n, result);
        } else {
            result = fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2);
            System.out.printf("%sfib(%s)%n", blanks(4*fibCount), n);
        }
```

where `blanks(b)` returns a string of `b` blanks.  You can use `StringBuilder` to create the blank string, or something like:

```
String blanks = String.format("%" + numOfBlanks + "s", "");
```

[**Note:** according to a comment on another answer, this does not work if `numOfBlanks` is 0.]

Or you can replace `fibCount` with a `String fibIndent`, and instead of `fibCount++` use

```
fibIndent += "    ";
```

after saving the previous version.

Another thing to consider: if this were production code, I would recommend passing another parameter to the recursive routine, instead of using static variables.  Trying to handle static variables with a recursive routine is just messy and error-prone, even in single-threaded programs.  The recursive parameter should be a value parameter or an immutable object that is copied by each invocation before passing it to the next one.  In this case, the "recursive depth" (your `fibCount`) could be the parameter.  I don't recommend passing a reference to an object that all recursive invocations would share, because that is almost as error-prone as using a static variable (although more thread-safe).

[Note: I've spend much of my career working on a recursive-descent compiler, so a lot of these issues are very familiar to me.]

[Finally: I know this is just for practice, but don't use recursion to compute Fibonacci numbers.  Doing so gives you an exponential algorithm, instead of a linear algorithm as a straightforward loop would be.  This is because the recursive algorithm performs a huge amount of redundant work, computing the result for the same argument many multiples of times.]